# Pyspark - Creating a dataframe by user defined aggregate function and pivoting

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aggregate-functions

I need to write a user defined aggregate function that captures the number of days between previous discharge_date and following admit_date for each consecutive visits.

I will also need to pivot on the "PERSON_ID" values.

I have the following input_df :

**`input_df :`**

```python
+---------+----------+--------------+
|PERSON_ID|ADMIT_DATE|DISCHARGE_DATE|
+---------+----------+--------------+
|      111|2018-03-15|    2018-03-16|
|      333|2018-06-10|    2018-06-11|
|      111|2018-03-01|    2018-03-02|
|      222|2018-12-01|    2018-12-02|
|      222|2018-12-05|    2018-12-06|
|      111|2018-03-30|    2018-03-31|
|      333|2018-06-01|    2018-06-02|
|      333|2018-06-20|    2018-06-21|
|      111|2018-01-01|    2018-01-02|
+---------+----------+--------------+
```

First, I need to group by each person and sort the corresponding rows by ADMIT_DATE. That would yield "input_df2".

**`input_df2:`**

```python
+---------+----------+--------------+
|PERSON_ID|ADMIT_DATE|DISCHARGE_DATE|
+---------+----------+--------------+
|      111|2018-01-01|    2018-01-03|
|      111|2018-03-01|    2018-03-02|
|      111|2018-03-15|    2018-03-16|
|      111|2018-03-30|    2018-03-31|
|      222|2018-12-01|    2018-12-02|
|      222|2018-12-05|    2018-12-06|
|      333|2018-06-01|    2018-06-02|
|      333|2018-06-10|    2018-06-11|
|      333|2018-06-20|    2018-06-21|
+---------+----------+--------------+
```

**`The desired output_df :`**

```python
+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|PERSON_ID_DISTINCT| FIRST_DIFFERENCE|SECOND_DIFFERENCE|THIRD_DIFFERENCE|
+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
|               111| 1 month 26 days |          13 days|         14 days|
|               222|           3 days|              NAN|             NAN|
|               333|           8 days|           9 days|             NAN|
+------------------+-----------------+-----------------+----------------+
```

I know the maximum number a person appears in my input_df, so I know how many columns should be created by :

```python
print input_df.groupBy('PERSON_ID').count().sort('count', ascending=False).show(5)
```

Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pyspark.sql.functions.datediff()` to compute the difference between two dates in days. In this case, you just need to compute the difference between the current row's `ADMIT_DATE` and the previous row's `DISCHARGE_DATE`. You can do this by using `pyspark.sql.functions.lag()` over a `Window`.

For example, we can compute the duration between visits in days as a new column `DURATION`.

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
from pyspark.sql import Window

w = Window.partitionBy('PERSON_ID').orderBy('ADMIT_DATE')
input_df.withColumn(
        'DURATION',
        f.datediff(f.col('ADMIT_DATE'), f.lag('DISCHARGE_DATE').over(w))
    )\
    .withColumn('INDEX', f.row_number().over(w)-1)\
    .sort('PERSON_ID', 'INDEX')\
    .show()
#+---------+----------+--------------+--------+-----+
#|PERSON_ID|ADMIT_DATE|DISCHARGE_DATE|DURATION|INDEX|
#+---------+----------+--------------+--------+-----+
#|      111|2018-01-01|    2018-01-02|    null|    0|
#|      111|2018-03-01|    2018-03-02|      58|    1|
#|      111|2018-03-15|    2018-03-16|      13|    2|
#|      111|2018-03-30|    2018-03-31|      14|    3|
#|      222|2018-12-01|    2018-12-02|    null|    0|
#|      222|2018-12-05|    2018-12-06|       3|    1|
#|      333|2018-06-01|    2018-06-02|    null|    0|
#|      333|2018-06-10|    2018-06-11|       8|    1|
#|      333|2018-06-20|    2018-06-21|       9|    2|
#+---------+----------+--------------+--------+-----+
```

Notice, I also added an `INDEX` column using `pyspark.sql.functions.row_number()`. We can just filter for `INDEX > 0` (because the first value will always be `null`) and then just pivot the DataFrame:

```python
input_df.withColumn(
        'DURATION',
        f.datediff(f.col('ADMIT_DATE'), f.lag('DISCHARGE_DATE').over(w))
    )\
    .withColumn('INDEX', f.row_number().over(w) - 1)\
    .where('INDEX > 0')\
    .groupBy('PERSON_ID').pivot('INDEX').agg(f.first('DURATION'))\
    .sort('PERSON_ID')\
    .show()
#+---------+---+----+----+
#|PERSON_ID|  1|   2|   3|
#+---------+---+----+----+
#|      111| 58|  13|  14|
#|      222|  3|null|null|
#|      333|  8|   9|null|
#+---------+---+----+----+
```

Now you can rename the columns to whatever you desire.

Note: This assumes that `ADMIT_DATE` and `DISCHARGE_DATE` are of type `date`.

```python
input_df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- PERSON_ID: long (nullable = true)
# |-- ADMIT_DATE: date (nullable = true)
# |-- DISCHARGE_DATE: date (nullable = true)
```

Comment: Paul, thank you a lot for your answer, it works great! I have an additional question about dynamically renaming multiple columns in a for loop. 
I checked @zero323 's answer. Let's say currently we have `output_df2`. This way works:
     `mapping =dict(zip(['1', '2','3'], ['1_dif_time', '2_dif_time', '3_dif_time' ]))` and then
     `output_df2 = output_df2.select([col(c).alias(mapping.get(c, c)) for c in output_df2.columns])`

However, I would like do it in a for loop in a more effective way. Could you please help me?

Comment: What's wrong with the way you are doing it now? That's about as effective as it gets. One alternative is something like `for c in {'1', '2', '3'}: output_df2 = output_df2.withColumnRenamed(c, c + "_dif_time")`. It's hard to answer follow ups in the comments. Please consider asking a new question if you have further doubts, but be sure to clarify in the question why it is not a duplicate of the existing post.